# How to add two different counter values in grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have two counters let's say c1 and c2. How to show the total count c1+c2 in the Grafana panel?
When I do c1+c1 values are shown correctly on the panel but when I do c1+c2 it returns a null value.

Query working:

```
sum by (level1,level2,level3)
(
  sum_over_time(
    sponsored_products_service_counter_total{
      cloud_zone=~"$cluster_id",
      job="$app",
      namespace="$namespace",
      container="$container",
      pod=~"$pod"
    }[$__interval]
  )
) + sum by (level1,level2,level3)
(
  sum_over_time(
    sponsored_products_service_counter_total{
      cloud_zone=~"$cluster_id",
      job="$app",
      namespace="$namespace",
      container="$container",
      pod=~"$pod"
    }[$__interval]
  )
)
```

Query resulting in null value:

```
sum by (level1,level2,level3)
(
  sum_over_time(
    sponsored_products_service_counter_total{
      cloud_zone=~"$cluster_id",
      job="$app",
      namespace="$namespace",
      container="$container",
      pod=~"$pod"
    }[$__interval]
  )
) + sum by (level1,level2,level3)
(
  sum_over_time(
    display_ads_service_counter_total{
      cloud_zone=~"$cluster_id",
      job="$app",
      namespace="$namespace",
      container="$container",
      pod=~"$pod"
    }[$__interval]
  )
)
```

Result for only sponsored_products_service_counter_total
[image: sponsored_products_service_counter_total]

Result for only display_ads_service_counter_total
[image: display_ads_service_counter_total]

Comment: Most likely you have issue with labels. Please [edit] the question and add examples of your metrics. And also specify if you metrics always have only one active time series.

Comment: Added my usecase counters. yes have only one active time series. For first case I am getting twice value sponsored_products_service_counter_total counter, while second case I am getting null value

Comment: okay I think I got your point. Actually level1,level2 and level3 are variable based on request headers. So they can differ based on headers passed for each request.

Comment: Then simple `+` is not enough. Look into [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) for binary operators. Depending on how much rows is produced by operands in may need simple `+ on()` or something with [`group_left()`/`group_right()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches)

Comment: I meant `sum by (level1,level2,level3)(sum_over_time (sponsored_products_service_counter_total{cloud_zone=~"$cluster_id",job="$app",namespace="$namespace",container="$container",pod=~"$pod"}[1h]))` and `sum by (level1,level2,level3)(sum_over_time(display_ads_service_counter_total{cloud_zone=~"$cluster_id",job="$app",namespace="$namespace",container="$container",pod=~"$pod"}[$__interval]))` as text from prometheus' web ui page.

Comment: total count I have named variable name- totalCount-{{level1}}-{{level2}}-{{level3}}

Comment: It is very strange. Your last columns should be matched. Look into exact values of your labels, maybe something with spaces or same looking letters from different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @marklaex for clearing doubt.
simple + is not enough. Look into [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) for binary operators. Depending on how much rows is produced by operands in may need simple + on() or something with group_left()/group_right()